# Create second custom 404 page for selected post type

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, page-template, 404-error

I created a new custom post type called `event`, which works fine.

I also created a custom `404` page template, which is shown if a event/page/post is not found.

But now the hard part, i want to create a custom 404 page for event post type. So this 404 page is only shown if a event is not found.  But the default 404 page should still work with posts or pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use conditional code inside of `404.php`, to output different content/markup for the post-type
2. Intercept the template at `template_redirect`, and include a separate template file for a 404 for the post-type.

Personally, I'd go with option 1, as it is easier and more intuitive.

Comment: On the other hand, using a `404-posttype.php` like `single-posttype.php` might be easier to understand for the next developer.

Comment: But the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) doesn't account for anything other than `404.php`, so support would have to be added by filtering `template_include`; thus I'm not sure how intuitive it would be for a subsequent developer?

Comment: You could call that file from `404.php` too (and `return;` then), so implementation details are rather open. I had the file list in mind.